# Which LayoutParams class to import while working with TableLayout?

Tags: java, android

I'm appending rows to a `TableLayout` programmatically by looping over an `ArrayList`. At present, the table columns are set to `WRAP_CONTENT` and because of this are not stretching to occupy full width of the device.

After going through some SO threads, I found this piece of code:

```
LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Upon using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, a long list of classes come up and I'm not sure which class to import.

#### Activity File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_feed_history"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="abc.def.FeedHistory">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:id="@+id/todayTable">
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

#### Java File

```
.
.
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.todayTable);
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
row.setLayoutParams(lparams);

TextView textView= new TextView(this);
textView.setText("Row Text);
textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
row.addView(textView);
table.addView(row);
```

#### FYI

I've already tried `TableLayout.LayoutParams`, `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, and `RelativeLayout.LayoutParms`. All result in the table getting vanished when viewed in emulator.

[image: Expected]

Comment: always the one of the outer container

Comment: So in this case `RelativeLayout` since it is the root element? But I already tried with that and got blank screen.

Comment: Views in a `TableLayout` need `TableLayout.LayoutParams`. In other words the first choice right at the top - Android Studio/IntelliJ is very smart when it comes to figuring out throw stuff for you.

Comment: if you want to call `setLayoutParams` on `TableLayout`, than it is correct

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final TableRow row = new TableRow(context);

TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText("0");
  textView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
row.addView(textView, 0);
```

Comment: This seems to be working. Can you please explain what's happening in there?

Answer (score 0):

The safest `LayoutParams` to import in to other layouts is `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`.  The reason is all Views will be placed inside a `ViewGroup` because all Layouts are `ViewGroups`.

Sometimes though, you need a little more detail.  In that case, you need to use the `LayoutParam` of the direct parent.  Otherwise you get a `ClassCastException`.

In the case of a `TableLayout`, you would create your `TableRow`, then pass in a `TableLayout.LayoutParams` like so:

```
TableLayout layout = methodToGetLayout();

TableLayout.LayoutParams lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParmas(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
lp.layout_weight = 1;

TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
row.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

So in this case, you can manually set the LayoutParams that are specific to a `TableLayout.LayoutParams` that don't exist in a generic `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`.  If you don't need these though, then you can stick with a generic `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` and be just fine.